# Where is '/etc/hosts' in XAMPP 1.7.7?

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I want to make a virtual host using XAMPP 1.7.7 under Ubuntu 12.04, I followed an [instruction](http://mintarticles.com/read/software-articles/multiple-virtual-hosts-in-xampplampp-in-ubuntu,977/) to add a line of virtual hostname in `/opt/lampp/etc/hosts`. But when I search the file, the file does not exists. When I create a new one, it's still not working.

Is virtual hosts configuration has changed in some latest XAMPP versions?

Comment: Wild guess: Did you mix up the `etc` folder in the `xamp` folder and the one in root (`/etc`)?

Comment: Why don't you use standard LAMP stack in Ubuntu, isn't it more convenient and configurable. ?

Comment: When you downloaded the package, what program did you choose to unpack it? Do you know the folder where the software was unpacked? Are there any files in `/opt` and `/opt/lampp`?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial tells you to edit `/etc/hosts` and not `/opt/lampp/etc/hosts`.